# Nuxt: Manifest file not found

Tags: nuxt.js

My Nuxt application is throwing the following error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/manifest.e8b5c21c.json 404 (Not Found)
manifest.e8b5c21c.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Furthermore, the application keeps serving versions of pages and components that no longer exist. I can't even find any evidence of these versions, yet somehow they (and their bugs) are being rendered in the application.

I have tried all of the following:

- Closing the browser tab and reopening it.
- Restarting the Nuxt server (I'm running it through `npm run dev`).
- Deleting `.nuxt/components`.
- Deleting a stray `dist` folder.
- Deleting the entire `.nuxt` folder.

I'm completely stumped, and this is stopping my development cold. What is the problem, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Having the same here after publish to Azure App Service... did you find the reason? What is weird is if I check the file in the folder, it is in there! 

Comment: same problem. This is insanely frustrating

Comment: I tried adding the pwa module to the buildModules options but no luck. Curious thing, if I use an anonymous window it doesn't complain about the manifest.

Comment: I'm also facing the issue at https://farhanshares.com - still no luck on solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple run the below command. I fixed same issue using below commad

```
rm -rf dist && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package.lcok.json && npm i && npm run build
```

After you just restart your server. I restart my pm2 server using below command.

```
pm2 restart client
```